# Extracting unique values from all the datasets in a SAS library

Tags: sas

I need to extract all the unique/distinct values of some common variables across all the datasets in a SAS library. I tried following code, but is there a better way of having this on one dataset.

```
%macro dslist(); 
proc sql noprint;
select  memname into :mylist separated by ' '
from dictionary.tables where libname= "VIEW" and upcase(memname) like "data_%"
;
quit;

%put &mylist;
  data _null_;
       datanum = countw("&mylist");
       call symput('Dataset', put(datanum, 10.));
  run;
%put #######&Dataset;

proc sql ;
%do i = 1 %to  &Dataset ;
  %let dataname=view.%scan(&mylist,&i,%str( ));
  create table %scan(&mylist,&i,%str( )) as 
   select distinct id,visit 
   from &dataname 
   order by id,visit
  ;
%end;
quit;
%mend;
%dslist;
```

I use proc append after this step to set all the datasets and then remove duplicates.

Also, if someone knows Hash approach for better efficiency!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of datasets is small you might just generate one SQL statement that will select and de-dup.  But there is a limit on the number of tables that a single SQL statement can reference.  Just like there is a limit on the number of dataset names that can fit into a the single macro variable your current code it generating.

So to make something that is more robust you could use a data step view to combine the data and PROC SORT to de-dup.

First get the list of datasets that have both ID and VISIT variables and meet your other criteria.

```
proc sql ;
create table dslist as
  select  catx('.',libname,nliteral(memname)) as dsname
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname= "VIEW"
    and memname like %upcase("data_%")
    and upcase(name) in ('ID' 'VISIT')
  group by 1
  having count(*)=2
;
quit;
```

Then use that list to define a data step view that combines just the ID and VISIT variables from all of them.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set dslist end=eof;
  file code lrecl=72;
  if _n_=1 then put 'data id_visit_v / viwe=id_visit_v;' / '  set ' @;
  put dsname '(keep=id visit) ' @;
  if eof then put ';' / 'run;' ;
run;

%include code / source2;
```

Then use PROC SORT to get the set of distinct ID*VISIT combinations.

```
proc sort data=id_visit_v nodupkey out=id_visit ;
  by id visit;
run;
```

Clean up.

```
proc delete data=id_visit_v (memtype=view);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how your code is actually working with the following `upcase(memname) like "data_%"`.

Creating fake data

```
libname view "/home/kermit/folder";

data view.data_A;
    call streaminit(123);
    array _{5} $ ('s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k');

    do i=1 to 100000;
        id=rand("integer", 1, 1000);
        j=rand('integer', 1, dim(_));
        visit=_[j];
        output;
    end;
    drop i j _:;
run;

data view.data_B;
    call streaminit(123);
    array _{5} $ ('s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k');

    do i=1 to 100000;
        id=rand("integer", 1, 1000);
        j=rand('integer', 1, dim(_));
        visit=_[j];
        output;
    end;
    drop i j _:;
run;

data view.data_C;
    call streaminit(123);
    array _{5} $ ('s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k');

    do i=1 to 100000;
        id=rand("integer", 1, 1000);
        j=rand('integer', 1, dim(_));
        visit=_[j];
        output;
    end;
    drop i j _:;
run;
```

Consolidate in one single table

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats(libname,'.',memname,"(keep= id visit)") into :mylist separated by ' '
from dictionary.tables where libname="VIEW" and upcase(memname) like "DATA_%"
;
quit;

data have;
set &mylist.;
run;
```

Extract all unique values of `id` and `visit`

```
proc sort data=have out=want nodupkey; by id visit; run;
```

```
 NOTE: There were 300000 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
 NOTE: 295000 observations with duplicate key values were deleted.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 5000 observations and 2 variables.
 NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT a utilisé (Durée totale du traitement) :
       real time           0.08 seconds
       user cpu time       0.14 seconds
       system cpu time     0.02 seconds
       memory              23404.76k
       OS Memory           51740.00k
```